# Como mostrar datos de Firebase en Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

Buenas, tengo en mi BDD de FireBase unos datos (Nombre, Apellidos, DNI) que estan creados en base a un Correo.

He estado buscando como mostrar en una pantalla de Android esos Datos pero no encuentro nada, alguien tiene alguna idea de como podria mostrarlos??

Y otra cosa mas, como he dicho cada cuenta esta creada con un correo, no hay forma de poner el Correo en vez de una Clave Aleatoria? No lo he visto por ningun lado.

[image: Aqui una foto de como estan los datos en FireBase]

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un item en Firebase con el identificador que necesitas de la siguiente manera:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuarios")
                           .child(email).setValue(userInfo);
```

Pero ten en cuenta que el "key" de cualquier registro de firebase no puede llevar ninguno de los siguientes caracteres, asi que no puedes usar el correo como tal por el punto.

- . (period)
- $ (dollar sign)
- [ (left square bracket)
- ] (right square bracket)
- '#' (hash or pound sign)
- / (forward slash)

Para desplegar la información te recomiendo el RecyclerView, puedes leer [aca](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es) sobre el componente

Answer (score 0):

En firebase al crear un nuevo nodo la clave que autogenera es un `UID` el cual para obtenerla es con `getkey`.

```
final String UID=databaseReference.getKey();
```

Pero si quieres retornar todos lo nodos usa un `recyclerview` para lo cual crearas un `ViewHolder` y necesitaras crear un `layout` en el sera el contenedor de cada nodo que se creara a partir de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente  debes crear es una instancia a tu tabla "usuarios"

2. Implementar un recyclerView con su respectivo adapter
3. Implementar el listener
4. Imprimir valores

   ```
   private DatabaseReference userDatabase
   //en el onCreate creas la instancia
   userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseReference.USUARIOS_REFERENCE);
   //Creas tu adapter y recycler y agregamos el listener
   ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               Usuarios users = snapshot.getValue(Usuarios.class);
               list_usuarios.add(users);
               Log.d("users",users.getUser() + "usename -> " +  
           users.getEmail());

           }
           tuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   };
   userDatabase.addValueEventListener(userListener);
   ```